# Update information when email is sent and uncheck box

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like,if possible, to enhance the code in way that it indicates on the column F when the email has been sent. Like this line:

> Latest update: Mail sent @Wed Jun 03 2020 23:05:18 GMT-0400

Also, I'd appreciate if an option is added to uncheck the box once the email is sent.

```
    function EnvoiIDCourriel() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Liste").activate();
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var LR = SS.getLastRow()

  var TemplateTexte = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  //Permet d'utiliser le corps du courriel qui se trouve dans l'onglet Template


  //Logger.log(NomCandidat);

  //Cette ligne permet de passer à travers de toutes les lignes inscrites
  var fileId = "1uLc_a5t2w1DFsDujpdMYTS7wYi5RtK8N";  // Added: Please set the file ID of the logo image.
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();  // Added
  var values = SS.getRange("A2:E" + SS.getLastRow()).getValues();
      values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus]) => {
             if (check === true) {
   var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
   var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne";
   var html = CorpsMessage.replace(/\n/g, '<br>').replace('{LOGO}', '<img src="cid:logo">');  // Added
    try{
   GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage, {htmlBody: html, inlineImages: {logo: blob}}); // Modified
   SS.getRange("F5").setFontColor("#228B22");
   SS.getRange("F5").setValue("Latest update: Mail sent @" + new Date());  
    }catch(err){
      SS.getRange("F5").setFontColor("#FF0000")
      SS.getRange("F5").setValue("Alert! Error: " + "  " + new Date() + "  " + e.message)
  }
}

});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to send an email, when the checkbox of the column "A" has the checked checkbox.
- You want to put `"Latest update: Mail sent @" + new Date()` to the column "F" of the same row when the email is sent.
- You want to put `"Alert! Error: " + "  " + new Date() + "  " + e.message` to the column "F" of the same row when the email is NOT sent.
- You want to uncheck the checkbox of the row.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In `forEach()`, when `values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus], i))` is used, the ranges for the same row of the columns "A" and "F" are `SS.getRange("F" + (i + 2))` and `SS.getRange("A" + (i + 2))`, respectively. I think that your goal can be achieved using this.
- I think that in your script, `e.message` is `err.message`.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
      values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus]) => {
             if (check === true) {
   var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
   var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne";
   var html = CorpsMessage.replace(/\n/g, '<br>').replace('{LOGO}', '<img src="cid:logo">');  // Added
    try{
   GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage, {htmlBody: html, inlineImages: {logo: blob}}); // Modified
   SS.getRange("F5").setFontColor("#228B22");
   SS.getRange("F5").setValue("Latest update: Mail sent @" + new Date());  
    }catch(err){
      SS.getRange("F5").setFontColor("#FF0000")
      SS.getRange("F5").setValue("Alert! Error: " + "  " + new Date() + "  " + e.message)
  }
}

});
```

To:

```
values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus], i) => { // Modified
  if (check === true) {
    var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
    var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne";
    var html = CorpsMessage.replace(/\n/g, '<br>').replace('{LOGO}', '<img src="cid:logo">');
    var range = SS.getRange("F" + (i + 2));  // Added
    try {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage, {htmlBody: html, inlineImages: {logo: blob}});
      range.setFontColor("#228B22");  // Modified
      range.setValue("Latest update: Mail sent @" + new Date());  // Modified
      SS.getRange("A" + (i + 2)).uncheck();  // Added
    } catch(err) {
      range.setFontColor("#FF0000") // Modified
      range.setValue("Alert! Error: " + "  " + new Date() + "  " + err.message)  // Modified
    }
  }
});
```